# Javascript DOM, get node text without losing spacing info

Tags: javascript, dom

I am using javascript and want to traverse the HTML tree, getting all the text as it appears to the user. However, I am losing spacing information.

Let's say I have two docs:

```
<html>XXX<p>YY    YY</p><html>

<html>XXX<p>YY&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;YY</p><html>
```

The first one will appear with 1 space between the Ys. The second will have 3 spaces. However,  if I traverse the tree and, for each #text node, use:

```
text = node.nodeValue;
```

then the text for both nodes will have 3 spaces. I no longer know which one has the "real" nbsp spaces. I can use node.innerHTML for the p elements, which will show the nbsp, but I don't think that I can use innerHTML to get just the XXX text (without some kind of text subtraction).

I could just get innerHTML of the whole document and parse that. However, I also need to get the computed style of each element, which I am going to get using

```
window.getComputedStyle(theElement).getPropertyValue("text-align");
```

So, I will be traversing each node. Also, innerHTML shows the source as is, while traversing the nodes "fixes" html errors, adding end tags, etc. That's a good thing and something I'd like to keep.

Comment: Interesting question. Can you show your current traversal code for reference?

Comment: I created a function that I call recursively. The function gets the nodeName of the element and, if it's a #text element, gets the nodeValue. For each child (element.childNodes) it calls the function, returning the name and value information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you test by charCode? I believe a regular space is `32`, while `&nbsp;` is `160`.

Comment: You're right! I tested it and it works. So the information isn't really lost. It's just that, in the way that I viewed it, they were both displayed as spaces. Knowing this, I can probably also find other ways to get the information (for example, in my python code, after sending the info in the form). Now I also need to think about what other conversions that I need to do. I suppose all the html entities, etc.  Thanks!